# Increase space between title and text of AlertDialog in Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog, spacing

In a simple `AlertDialog` like the following

```kotlin
AlertDialog(
    modifier = Modifier,
    title = {
        Text(text = "Title")
    },
    text = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            TextButton() {
                Text("Text 1")
            }
            TextButton() {
                Text("Text 2")
            }
        }
    },
    confirmButton = {},
    dismissButton = {}
)
```

how can I set a spacing between title and the first `TextButton`?
I tried to set a `.padding(top = X.dp)` to the Column, or the first text button, but this seems to only create a space at the bottom of the `AlertDialog`.
Also setting a custom `.height(X.dp)` did not work.

I'm using Compose `1.0.3`

Answer (score 5):

Is now possible using the new [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#AlertDialog(kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties)) from [Compose Material 3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3).
The default spacing between `title` and `text` is much more reasonable and it is also possible to add `Modifier.padding()` or `Spacer()` to both.

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha01")
```

```
androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest = {
        openDialog.value = false
    },
    title = {
        Text(text = "Title", modifier = Modifier.padding(50.dp))
    },
    text = {
        Spacer(Modifier.height(50.dp))
        Text(text = "Turned on by default")
    },
    confirmButton = {
        TextButton(
            onClick = {
                openDialog.value = false
            }
        ) {
            Text("Confirm")
        }
    },
    dismissButton = {
        TextButton(
            onClick = {
                openDialog.value = false
            }
        ) {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is **NOT an answer**. It only provides info on why this is not possible.

The requirement seems not achievable at this point (6th Oct 2021) with the current compose version (1.0.3).
Will update this once that is possible.

The `AlertDialog` code does not respect the padding values provided.

`AlertDialog.kt`

```
// Baseline distance from the first line of the text to the last line of the title
private val TextBaselineDistanceFromTitle = 36.sp
```

The text offset used for the positioning is calculated like this.

```
val textOffset = if (titlePlaceable == null) {
    TextBaselineDistanceFromTop.roundToPx()
} else {
    TextBaselineDistanceFromTitle.roundToPx()
}
```

The distance between the first text in the text composable and the last text in the title composable is always `36.sp`.

The Alert Dialog code in compose seems too hackish currently and I could see a few TODO's in the code.

Hopefully, the code will be changed to handle more scenarios soon.

Answer (score 4):

As @Abhimanyu perfectly explains why it's not working right now, here's the workaround I'm using to achieve the desired padding: putting the title in the content. `AlertDialog`'s `title` param is optional, so it can be omitted/set to `null`, and instead the actual title can be put in the `text` parameter (which holds the dialog content).

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    AlertDialog(
        title = null,
        text = {
            Column {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp),
                    text = "Actual title"
                )

                // Rest of the dialog content
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this composable as first child inside `Column`

```
@Composable
fun HackySpacer(space: Dp) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(space)
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(text = "")
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, but it works for my usecase.